# Can I keep my existing C files when moving from GCC 3.4.3 to GCC 8.2?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm standing up a new architectural stack, and in the old (current-state) stack I'm using GCC 3.4.3 for my C Files. Since I'm updating to a MUCH newer OS, wondered if I could continue to use my existing C files (that works with GCC 3.4.3) in my future-state stack - which will use GCC 8.2. I would rather not have to re-write files in C++, unless I have to.

Is GCC 8.2 backward compatible with GCC 3.4.3 and, if not, what could be the cost?

Comment: C is not a scripting language. Chances are that you might have issues while compiling the old code on new GCC.

Comment: what do you mean by scripts?

Comment: Perhaps just try to check if there is any problem ?

Comment: C is a standardised language, so if all the rules were followed originally it should work perfectly. that said, compiler writers have added lots of new warnings and errors over the years. They may reveal some subtle issues that you should consider fixing.

Comment: [GCC 3.4.3 was released on 2004-11-04](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) — that's a long time ago.  If you're referring to your build scripts, you may still be able to use them.  If you're referring to your programs' source code, you should still be able to use it, but there may be problems that GCC 8.2 (why not 9.2?) spots that were not spotted by GCC 3.4.3.  You should fix any problems (bugs) that the new compiler reports.

Comment: A lot of people are going to have difficulty understanding the phrase "C scripts". C source files are not generally referred to as "scripts". That term is typically reserved for (interpreted) scripting languages like Bash and Python. If you're asking about C source files, files containing C code, I suggest you edit your question and eliminate the word "scripts". If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: A lot of C code that works correctly with gcc 3.4.3 will also work correctly with gcc 8.2, but some won't. Code that doesn't work will *probably* require only minor updates, but that's not certain. The only way to tell is to compile your code with gcc 8.2 and see what happens. We can't see your code, so that's probably the best information we can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler version matters a lot less than the operating system itself. Changes to the API of underlying libraries, at least those outside of C's Standard Library, are going to cause the most trouble.

The C language itself hasn't changed significantly in that time, or at least not in a way that would cause a lot of problems. You may need to update some `#ifdef` type statements to reflect newer compiler conventions, but that's about it.